# A Quick Question on Increasing Sequences and the Supremum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\emptyset\not= A\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $a:=\sup A<\infty$. Now by leastness of the supremum we know that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an $a_n\in A$ such that $a_n>a-1/n$ and so $\lim_na_n=a$.

Is the sequence $\{a_n\}$ an increasing sequence, if so how can you show it?  If it is not necessarily increasing does there always exist an increasing sequence in $A$ the converges to the $\sup A$, if so how can you show it? Any help is greatly needed, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to believe that the $a_n$ form an increasing sequence by your definition, since your only constraint is $a_n > 1- 1/n$, while $a_{n-1}$ could very well be substantially closer to $a$.

This can be fixed by forcing the $a_i$ to be increasing when your choose your sequence.  Alternatively, you can take the $\{a_i\}$ as chosen by your method, and choose a new sequence $\{b_i\}$ defined by $b_{i} = \max\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_i\}$.  Then it is easy to see that the $b_i$ are an increasing sequence that also converges to $a$.

(Note that this construction very well might not be strictly increasing.  The result is false if you force $a_i < a_{i+1}$ for all $i$.  This is possible if $a \in A$ and $a$ is an isolated point, such as $A = \{a\}$.)

Comment: Thank you, this cleared up things for me but then how would you construct an increasing sequence while not using the method I outlined and then taking the maximum of the first n terms?